# Paypal referenced transaction with Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm looking for some gem/tutorials on how to implement referenced transactions in Rails 3. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Active Merchant is a gem that supports many payment providers, including Paypal. http://www.activemerchant.org/